# How to run multiple Async HTTP requests in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wp-cron, apache, http-api

In my plugin, I want to call 10 or more HTTP requests asynchronously in WordPress so that I need not wait for the response of anyone. Is there any way in Wordpress that supports this and also compatible with different WordPress versions?

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/techcrunch/wp-async-task

Comment: Is this project(wp-async-task ) still alive on WP 4.9(no commit for last 3 years)? Also, this seems to run a background process related to a hook and  bit doubtful if I can call multiple HTTP requests using that like we do in AJAX using promise

Comment: You can send multiple async HTTP requests using Ajax and can handle those request using ajax request handler https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins .

`wp-async-task` is still compatible with WordPress latest version and it handles async taks in server.

Comment: But I want to do it from backend using PHP and not from Javascript so AJAX might not help

Comment: Then `wp-async-task` is what you need. Please check the following links for more details
https://torquemag.io/2016/01/use-asynchronous-php-wordpress/

https://techcrunch.com/2014/07/31/wp-async-task-our-new-open-source-library/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924616/wp-async-task-dont-fire-run-action-method

Answer (score 5):

The (built-in) `Requests` class lets you call multiple requests simultaneously: [`Requests::request_multiple`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/request_multiple/).

```
<?php

$requests = Requests::request_multiple([
    [
        'url' => 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5acb821f2f00005300411631',
        'type' => 'GET',
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],

    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5acb821f2f00005300411631',
        'type' => 'POST',
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'data' => json_encode([
            'text' => 'My POST Data'
        ])
    ],
    [
        'url' => 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5acb82ee2f00005100411635',
        'type' => 'POST',
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'data' => json_encode([
            'text' => 'More POST Data'
        ])
    ],  
]);

foreach ($request as $request) {
    if ($request->status_code !== 200) {
        // handle error
    }
    // handle success
    echo $request->body;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `foreach` at the end is not complete. It's just there to demonstrate how to use it. You'll potentially also have to handle the `Requests_Exception`.